# Surprising segfault in C code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, factorial

I cannot understand how this code is causing a segfault when I run it, can anyone help me understand what is going on??

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long factorial(unsigned long long x, unsigned long long amt)
{
    if (x == 1ULL) return amt;
    else return factorial(x-1ULL, amt*x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < 10ULL ;i++) {
        printf("%llu\n", factorial(i, 1ULL));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think happens when you call `factorial(0, 1ULL)`? HINT: `x == 1ULL` is not true. The results are not surprising.

Comment: Oops now I feel stupid :(

Comment: Hah... no worries. Can't see the forest for the trees sometimes. You can simplify your factorial function, and don't need two arguments. In pseudo-C-code: `factorial(n) { if (n <= 1) return 1; else return n * factorial(n-1); }`

Comment: Better yet, replace the unreadable recursion with a readable loop. Then you would likely never had written this bug to begin with. As a bonus, the code turns much faster and safer, and also needs less memory. Recursion is really the very last resort, it should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

In the orginal code :

```
if (x == 1ULL) return amt;
```

is meant to be the exit condition for this recursive function `factorial`. However when a value of zero is passed to the function and given that the type of `x` is `unsigned long long`, first recursive call to the function `factorial` with the parameter `x-1ULL` would set the value of `x` to very large value (18446744073709551615 is what I got here). Successive recursive calls to `factorial` will gradually deplete the stack space allocated for the program to the point where you get a **segmentation fault**.

You should have been doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long factorial(unsigned long long x, unsigned long long amt)
{
        if (x == 0ULL) // Changed the exit condition, see Reference [1]
                return amt; // Bear in mind that the initial value for amt you passed is 1
        amt*=x; // See Reference [2]
        return factorial(x-1ULL, amt);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < 10ULL ;i++) {
                printf("%llu\n", factorial(i, 1ULL));
        }

}
```

**References**

1. The idea of the factorial (in simple terms) is used to compute the number of permutations (combinations) of arranging a set of n numbers. It can be said that an empty set can only be ordered one way, so 0! = 1. Check [this](https://zero-factorial.com/whatis.html).
2. I feel this is more readable than `factorial(x-1ULL, amt*x)`

**Note**

The `ULL` suffixes are redundant here and may be removed altogether.

Comment: Not my downvote. But perhaps because the answer is just a code listing without an explanation of what the problem is and how it is being fixed. And your formatting is a bit off too.

Comment: @kaylum: I agree :D.I have added the explanation. Though it is not an obligation, it would make sense to know why the downvote was for

Comment: Yes, I agree that downvotes should come with a reason. But IMHO your explanation still does not clearly explain the OP's problem - which is an infinete recursion caused by not correctly checking the recursion termination condition. I'm sure you understand the problem and solution. It's just not worded in a way that highlights the problem in the OP's original code. And your formatting is still off - the `return` statement is made to look like it is part of the `else` but it is not.

Comment: The `ULL` suffixes are all redundant here (and they make it slightly harder to read imo)

Comment: @M.M . I agree, but lemme keep that for the sake of minimum deviation from original code. I will put a note instead :D

Answer (score 2):

First, the segfaults are not necessarily caused be invalid pointer dereference. In this case, it is actually caused by infinite recursion and eventual running out of stack space. Why? The essential requirement of a recursion function is it has to finish and terminate the recursion at some state, if you look carefully your code, in function `factorial`, if `x` is 0, then the recursion will become endless and eventually crash your program. You can fix this by change the terminate condition to:

```
if (x <= 1ULL) return amt;
```

Comment: This is correct.  You are sending in `x=0`, and then it calls `factorial(x-1ULL, amt*x);`, which is the same as `factorial((-1)ULL, amt*x);`.  The -1 turns into a very large unsigned number, ending in a recursion that runs you out of stack space.

Comment: Technically this is not "infinite" recursion, but a very deep one. If one used `unsigned char` instead of `unsigned long long`, the first call would terminate near instantly and return `0`.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa To be precise that is correct, but we should not endorse such behavior. :)